# How do I set a logging level in a Kitura project generated using the project template?

Tags: swift, logging, environment-variables, kitura

I want to set the logging level of my Kitura project. The project is created with the `kitura init` command, which generates the project using a template. In the template, there is an `initializeLogging` method that sets the logging level of `HeliumLogger`:

```
func initializeLogging() {
    let manager = ConfigurationManager()
    manager.load(.environmentVariables)

    let logLevel: LoggerMessageType
    switch (manager["LOG_LEVEL"] as? String)?.lowercased() {
    case "error":
        logLevel = .error
    case "warning":
        logLevel = .warning
    case "info":
        logLevel = .info
    case "verbose":
        logLevel = .verbose
    case "debug":
        logLevel = .debug
    case "exit":
        logLevel = .exit
    case "entry":
        logLevel = .entry
    case "none", "false", "off", "disabled":
        return
    default:
        logLevel = .info
    }
    HeliumLogger.use(logLevel)
}
```

It seems to get an environment variable called `"LOG_LEVEL"`. Upon further inspection of what `manager.load` does, I worked out that it accesses `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment`, which I know I can set in the "Edit Schemes" screen in Xcode:

[image]

**However, this only works if I run the app with Xcode.** If I use `swift build`, then run the executable in the console. The logging level is back to "info". Clearly, setting it in "Edit Schemes" is not how I am *supposed* to set it...

What is the intended approach of setting the logging level?

---

I know I can just delete everything and write `HeliumLogger.use(.verbose)`, but I would like some late binding :) And I feel like the code in the code in the template is there for a reason...